Bulbs Burn Out in Wall Sconces
Does anyone know why the bulbs in some of my wall sconces burn out so quickly? Am I using the wrong bulbs? Should I be using another kind? I have used the example shown, cheap, made in China, LEDs.  This one is barely throwing off any light at all.  I've also tried glass tube bulbs both with a filament and with a LED.  Any thoughts?


Higher quality LED bulbs do last longer. You may not get what you pay for, but you never get what you're unwilling to pay for.

These are five feet off the floor with another eight or nine feet to the ceiling.  The sconces are half moon that are open at the top.  There is definitely heat but normal heat, nothing contained.

more info could help:   how much does usage differ?  what line voltage in your part of world?  are the lamps rated the same?  do your incandescent lamps (filament) have shorter lives in the same set of fixtures as the LED?  does the lamp life correlate with the breaker they are on?  Are the contacts clean and uncorroded?  Do you have any other electrical issues in the house? how confident are you that your impression matches actual fact?

The lamps are on full time, 7x24x365.  I'm in Canada, what's that 120v? Not sure what you mean "rated"? The lives of the bulbs isn't consistent, that could be related to what keshlam says above (low quality). They're all on the same breaker.  The contacts always look clean and un-corroded. No other electrical issues. I'm thinking I might buy a better quality package of bulbs and give them a go.

If both LED bulbs like in the picture, and regular glass tube halogen bulbs, burn out early in the same fixture, I would start to suspect the fixture...

You stated the bulbs "burn out quickly"  but also that the fixtures are on 24-7-365.  The fact that they are always on uses up the expected hours of life constantly. So the time between changing bulbs would be considerably shorter than lights used occasionally at night time.   So how often do you need to change bulbs?

True. The problem I'm seeing is that some of the bulbs last for ages and others are done in a week or two.  I'm leaning towards it being the quality of the bulbs we've used up to now.  We're going to give a try with some better quality bulbs to see if that makes a difference.

@Mitch I meant are the lamps rated for the same voltage as the mains supply. Yes, 120V in Canada. (I was getting at the possibility of say, 240V main with some lamps rated 120, 208, or 220V, vs. 240V - which could have accounted for life differences.).  Your answers to all the questions converge on differences in the quality of the lamps, rather than differences in conditions that might affect them.

The “Q type” bulb that your fixture manufacturer recommends is halogen. If that’s the glass tube type bulb you’re talking about, it could be blowing if you touched it with your bare fingers.
You can use LED instead, but here’s this from any-lamp.com:
“The lamp base is suitable for either 12 Volt or 230 Volt (mains) and never for both. When switching to LED, it's important to choose a product that has the same base so that you can simply replace your old halogen light with an LED one.”
I hope I understood the situation correctly, and I hope this helps. (Didn’t say, “sheds some light on it” ) Good luck!

Thanks for the info.  I've been wearing gloves to swap out the bulbs to avoid exactly what you mention.

Your sconce seems to use R7 bulbs.
I had lots of fixtures for these bulbs, and I could never find good quality bulbs for them. For some reason They always burn out. My guess is that's because R7 is uncommon, leading to low bulb sales, so there are no economies of scale to be made, so a high quality bulb would cost too much, so the market is inundated with garbage.
I ended up replacing all the luminaires with E27 and GU10, for which it is easy to find good quality long lasting bulbs with high CRI.

The bulbs are really hit and miss it seems.  The glass halogen bulbs do seem to last longer than the LED bulbs.

Is this fixture on a dimmer switch?  The dimmer has to be specifically a LED dimmer.  regular incandescent dimmers won't work on LED bulbs and can sometimes break them.  look up SCR vs ELTD for the physics of it.

They are not on a dimmer.
